# Iterating String.split() working differently than I expected

Tags: javascript, split, chess, fen

I am writing a simple javascript code to parse, and verify a chess position written in Forsyth–Edwards Notation (FEN).

The default chess position in this notation is given by,

`const defaultFEN = "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1";`

There are 6 components, I split the components by whitespace using String.split(" "), I now want to further split the first element of the resulting array by "/", which will give the state of each rank.

Running this code gives me an unintuitive result...

```
const defaultFEN = "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1";
const locations = defaultFEN.split(" ")[0];

for (let rank in locations.split("/")) {
   console.log(rank);
}
```

I expected the output to be 8 Strings, delimited by "/", in the first portion of the defaultFEN string. Instead I get the numbers 0-7 printing out.

Interestingly, If I manually access this array, `console.log(locations.split("/")[i])`, for any number i in the interval [0-7], I see the result I intended.

Why are the numbers 0-7 printing out when using the iterative loop, but it works exactly as intended if I use a normal index based for loop?

Comment: `for...in` iterates over the keys, not the values. Use `for...of` instead.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your split, but you should use `for..of` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)) instead:

```
for (let rank of locations.split("/")) {
   console.log(rank);
}
```

... as `for..in` loop iterates over *indexes* (and those are 0..7 for 8-element array).

As a sidenote, it's (usually) a good idea to use `const` (and not `let`) in this iteration, as variable is assigned a value once each loop (and usually shouldn't be reassigned):

```
for (const rank of locations.split("/")) {
   console.log(rank);
}
```

Comment: I see, thank you @raina77ow
This worked perfectly.. I just wasn't aware of the difference between ```of``` and ```in```